# Как отменить перенос флекс-элементв на следующую строку?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как отменить перенос флекс-элемента на другую строчку, чтобы он смотрелся на 768px вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня получается вот, хотя на чуть большем разрешении все нормально, но доходя до 768 переносится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код jsfiddle.net/Le9unvc2/

Сайт tempessj.beget.tech

Answer (score 4):

Можно добавить грид:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 886px) {
      .item{
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(4,auto);
      }
        
      .item .col.desc {
         grid-column: span 3;
       }
        
      .item .col.price {
        grid-column: span 4;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так.... http://jsfiddle.net/BlackStar1991/0wngqfa9/4/ (У вас очень плохо подобраны названия классов . сложно переназначать или расширять )

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  height: 100%;
  color: #989691;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #383736;
  margin-bottom: 18px !important;
  line-height: 0.75em;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.group {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #C4C4C4;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #F5F4F2;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.close:active {
  background-color: #E7E4DE;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.item .col.img {
  min-width: 178px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.col.desc {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-gap: 0 55px;
}

sup {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.grid__item {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.grid__title {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.grid__des {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #383736;
}

.grid__title,
.grid__des {
  display: block;
}

.item .col.desc .ach {
  display: flex;
}

.item .col.desc .ach div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.item .col.desc .ach div i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item .col.desc .ach div.viewing {
  color: #64B851;
  background-color: #F2FAF0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.item .col.desc .ach div.accreditation {
  color: #EB4B51;
  background-color: #FAF0F0;
}

.item .col.price {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-left: 1px solid #F0EEEB;
  padding-left: 30px;
  min-width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item .col.price .info .blue {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2794DB;
}

.item .col.price .currentprice {
  color: #383736;
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.item .col.price .info .red {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #EB4B51;
}

.item .col.price p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.item .col.price .button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  color: #383736;
  background-color: #FAC62D !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .col.price .button:hover {
  background-color: #F0B505 !important;
}

.item .col.price .button:active {
  background-color: #E1AB08 !important;
}

.item .col.price .button i {
  margin-right: 15px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 920px;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
  h2,
  .grid__item {
    margin-bottom: 13px !important;
  }
  .item {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .grid__item:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .item .col.desc .ach {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item .col.desc .ach div.viewing {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 886px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
    grid-gap: 0 52px;
  }
  .item {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item .col.desc .ach {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  .item .col.desc .ach div.viewing {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .col.price {
    width: 100%;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #F0EEEB;
    padding-top: 18px;
  }
  .item .col.price p {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="close">&#10006;</div>

    <div class="col group">

      <div class="col img">
        <img src="img/img.svg" alt="img">
      </div>


      <div class="col desc">
        <h2>2-к квартира</h2>

        <ul class="grid">
          <li class="grid__item">
            <span class="grid__title">Этаж</span>
            <span class="grid__des">3 из 19</span>
          </li>
          <li class="grid__item">
            <span class="grid__title">Высота потолков</span>
            <span class="grid__des">3,2 м</span>
          </li>
          <li class="grid__item three">
            <span class="grid__title">Отделка</span>
            <span class="grid__des">Предчистовая</span>
          </li>
          <li class="grid__item">
            <span class="grid__title">Общая площадь</span>
            <span class="grid__des">32,24 м<sup>2</sup></span>
          </li>
          <li class="grid__item">
            <span class="grid__title">Жилая площадь</span>
            <span class="grid__des">22,24 м<sup>2</sup></span>
          </li>
          <li class="grid__item">
            <span class="grid__title">Площадь кухни</span>
            <span class="grid__des">14,24 м<sup>2</sup></span>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="ach">
          <div class="viewing"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Вы были на просмотре</div>
          <div class="accreditation"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Дом аккредитован другим банком</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col price">

      <div class="info">
        Ваша цена по брони до <span class="blue">19 сентября</span>
        <span class="currentprice">3 312 666 Р</span>
        <p>Текущая цена у застройщика<br>дороже на <span class="red">324 825 Р</span></p>
      </div>

      <div class="button"><i class="fas fa-key"></i> Выбрать для покупки</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему  плохо названы? Ясно же, что к чему относится